# San Francisco To Hyderabad via Hong Kong with 15 hours layover, Do I need to to submit a Pre-arrival Registration for hotel stay in HKG transit area?

Tags: h1b-visas, hkg

I am a H1b visa holder working in USA traveling to India via Hong Kong where there is a 15h layover. I have seen that there is a Pre-arrival Registration Indians must go through if they are going to leave the transit area of HKG. However, I am planning to stay at a hotel called "Regal Airport Hotel" that is within the transit area of HKG.

Will I still need to go through the Pre-arrival Registration? What are my other options? I do not plan to leave the transit area in any case though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to consider going to a transit resting lounge. They do not have beds, but you can take a nap in a sofa, take a shower and eat.

Comment: Great, what about the safety of the luggage that I have? Is there any place where I can "store" my luggage meanwhile?

Comment: An airport lounge within the security area is a place where I would not worry much about luggage being stolen. I would just keep docs and money in some sort of travel pouch or hidden pocket.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regal Airport Hotel bills itself as a transit hotel but it is actually landside, so you do need to clear immigration to reach it (and thus you also need to fill out and bring a printed copy of your Pre-Arrival Registration). The hotel can be reached by a covered walkway from the Terminal 1 arrivals hall after you go through the customs channel.

AFAIK there are no hotels within the international transit area of HKG.

Comment: +1, I was at Regal Airport Hotel last week, definitely not in the transit area.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience and the research I've done during this trip, one does not necessarily need to leave the HKG Airport Transit Area to get some sleep. The lounges in the airport (Centurion, Plaza Premium Lounge) have some nice couches to sleep on. If a bed is really needed, there are two tiny `Refreshh by Aerotel` lounges within the airport that are somewhat expensive but decent to book small private cabins to get some sleep.

https://www.myaerotel.com/en-uk/find/china-regions/hong-kong-sar/hong-kong/refreshhh-by-aerotel-hong-kong/shower-massage-snooze